# Deixar item pre selecionado no P-TableRadioButton

Tags: angular, primeng

I want to leave preselected item in the table, I'm using primeNG-Angular table that has radio button. p-tableRadioButton. Can someone help me with this problem because I am not finding a way out. I can only generate the table so I can select.

Follow the code: **

```
<p-table [value]="pessoa" [(selection)]="pessoaSelecionado">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 3em"></th>
                <th>Nome</th>
                <th>idade</th>
                <th>Sexo</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData>
            <tr [pSelectableRow]="rowData.id">
                <td>
                    <p-tableRadioButton [value]="rowData.id" ></p-tableRadioButton>
                </td>
                <td>{{rowData.nome}}</td>
                <td>{{rowData.idade}}</td>
                <td>{{rowData.sexo}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="summary">
            <div style="text-align: left">
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

Comment: For future make sure content is written in english only, as majority of people understand english here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `pessoa` you want to the array `pessoaSelecionado`. It should work. If not, show us how your typescript looks like.